# Better way to assign values while declaring a list of class

Tags: c#

I am just declaring a list of class of a table created from linq to sql classes  and assigning values to them directly, I think this is lot of code. Please let me know if there is a way i can reduce it.

**My Code**

```
  List<className> obj = new List<className>() { new className { field1 = value1; field2 = value2}, new className { field 1 = value1}...;
```

Comment: I think you want to use `var` keyword: `var obj = new List<className>() { new className { field1 = value1; field2 = value2}, new className { field 1 = value1}, ... };`.

Comment: No just wanted to know if i can reduce code where we are declaring the new object like  `new className` and assinging its values

Comment: I have seen removing the `new className` code and just using paranthesis but it gave an error

Comment: for this code i need 5 objects in the list which are static and not going to change so I am declaring them like this

Comment: but it is not looking that good seeing the amount of code looks like a paragraph just wanted to know if there is a better way which makes my code look clean.

Comment: You're not going to significantly reduce the code to initialize these. You might define a constructor so that `new className(value1, value2, value3)`.

Comment: This looks the only way to reduce it

Comment: Just add break lines between every class and possible between every porperty - and your code will look readable

Comment: One of the downsides of the constructor style is you _must_ provide the arguments in the proper order or you'll get incorrect assignments.

Comment: make sense. all of your comment helped me

Comment: If the "assign values directly" means that you are assigning literal values to the new instances, and if the values are going to be fairly static, then you'd get the most mileage by using a factory pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this scenario, I would suggest to take a multiple-args constructor in your class - this would avoid the field-by-field assignment during the object creation.

For example, the class declaration may be:

```
 class MyClass
    {
        public string Field1 { get; set; }
        public string Field2 { get; set; }
        public string Field3 { get; set; }
        public string Field4 { get; set; }

        public MyClass()
        { }

        public MyClass(string f1, string f2, string f3 ,string f4)
        {
            Field1 = f1;
            Field2 = f2;
            Field3 = f3;
            Field4 = f4;
        }
    }
```

And then you initialize your `List<>` using this code:

```
List<MyClass> objects = new List<MyClass>()
   {
        new MyClass("f1", "f2", "f3", "f4"),
        new MyClass("f1", "f2", "f3", "f4")
   };
```

Here you provide the values to each `field` as you want.

Comment: make sense, I think this is the only possible way to reduce some code.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to show how "clean" collection initialization can be

```
var items = new List<MyClass>
{
    new MyClass
    {
        Field1 = "1value1",
        Field2 = "1value2",
        Field3 = "1value3",
        Field4 = "1value4"
    },
    new MyClass
    {
        Field1 = "2value1",
        Field2 = "2value2",
        Field3 = "2value3",
        Field4 = "2value4"
    }
};
```

With approach above you can initialize instance without providing values for all properties.
Formatting will save you from constraints to the constructor parameters.

I think, constructors should not be used only for save amount of written code.
Constructors are part of the type contract - which tell to the consumers that this class require all properties to be set for proper working.